# JavaScript find the last checked check box's index

Tags: javascript, html

If I have 10 checkbox and let say checkbox index 4,5,6,8 are checked.
I want to get the last index of the last **checked** checkbox ( `maximumIndex` ) **8** .
This is my javascript code ,

```
 var maximumIndex;
 var checkboxesList = $('.myCheckBox');
 checkboxesList .each(function (index) {
    if (checkboxesList[index].checked == true) {
        maximumIndex= index;
    }
});
```

The above code work fine .
But is there any way to find ?
I just don't want to loop for every checkbox .

Comment: This solution is the most obvious and i think one of the only ones, it wont have any Performance influence so i think you are fine.

Comment: You need to select the last element in the array of `checkboxesList`? You could use `checkboxesList.slice(-1).pop()`

Comment: not the last checkbox , the last **checked** checkbox :)

Comment: @zey , did any of the answers work for you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of `:last` and `:checked`.

Also you have to group them within a parent element.

```js
var maxindex = null;
$("#check").click(function() {
  $(".myCheckbox").removeClass('bigger');
  var $lastCheckbox = $(".myCheckbox:checked:last");
  $lastCheckbox.addClass('bigger');

  maxindex = $lastCheckbox.index();
  console.log(maxindex);
});
```

```css
.bigger {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="check">Check</button>
<br><br>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" value="1" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" value="2" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" value="3" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" value="4" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" value="5" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" value="6" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" value="7" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" value="8" />
</div>
```

Comment: This obviously does not work, try to check `3`, then press check , 3 will be scaled , now try to check `1` then press check again `3` will remain scaled

Comment: @HyyanAboFakher it does work to select the last element. I just hadn't cleaned the previously selected elements before. I fixed it a few seconds before your comment.

Comment: shouldnt it be `maxindex-1` ?

Comment: @Dementic I had to update the code. The indexes were weird because the checkboxes weren't grouped.

Comment: @Philer , this still does not work, the OP is asking to get the the last **checked** checkbox

Comment: `$lastCheckbox.index();` always return **0**

Comment: @zey is this what you are looking for ? please explain the correct behavior in your question

Comment: @HyyanAboFakher ,i'm asking to get the the last checked checkbox's **index**

Comment: did you try my code? You're probably not grouping the checkboxes within a common container

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution without any use of libraries.
Trigger a function on-click of the checkboxes which overwrites the max value if the checked element's index is greater than the max value;

```js
var maxValue=0;

    function updateMaxValue(index){
      if(index>maxValue)
        maxValue=index;
      console.log(maxValue);  
    }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" onclick="updateMaxValue(this.value)" value="1"/>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="updateMaxValue(this.value)" value="2"/>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="updateMaxValue(this.value)" value="3"/>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="updateMaxValue(this.value)" value="4"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var maximumIndex = 0;
var minimumIndex = 255;
$('.myCheckBox').on("change", function() {
  if (!this.checked && maximumIndex==maximumIndex) {
    console.log("No checkbox checked");
    return;
  }
  if (maximumIndex < this.name) {
    maximumIndex = this.name;
  }
  if (maximumIndex > this.name) {
    minimumIndex = this.name;
  }
  console.log("Last checked checkbox is " + maximumIndex);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheckBox" name="1" value="1">1<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheckBox" name="2" value="2">2<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheckBox" name="3" value="3">3<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheckBox" name="4" value="4">4<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheckBox" name="5" value="5">5<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheckBox" name="6" value="6">6<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheckBox" name="7" value="7">7<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheckBox" name="8" value="8">8<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheckBox" name="9" value="9">9<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheckBox" name="10" value="10">10<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `last()` function :

```js
var last = $('input.myCheckbox:checked').last();
alert(last.val())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<br><br>
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" value="3" />
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" value="4" />
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" value="5" />
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" value="6" />
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" value="7" checked/>
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" value="8" />
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get all checked items like this `$('.myCheckBox:checkbox:checked')` then after you can get last item and you could use [`index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) method.

**DEMO**

```js
$('#myButton').on('click', () => {
  var myCheckBox = $('.myCheckBox:checkbox:checked'),
    len = myCheckBox.length;
  
    console.log(len?($(myCheckBox[len - 1]).index() - 1):'No Selection');
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheckBox" />
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheckBox" />
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheckBox" />
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheckBox" />
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheckBox" />
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheckBox" />
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheckBox" />
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheckBox" />
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheckBox" />
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheckBox" />
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheckBox" />

<button id="myButton">Get Last Checked Index</button>
```